# clang-format space before semicolon?

Tags: clang-format

I believe that I picked up the habit of space before semicolon from the code-complete book (a recommendation to enhance statement visibility) :

```
int x ;
const char * v = "hi" ;
```

If I run clang-format on a block of code to fix up indenting, it strips out these additional spaces.  I can add them back in with a regex:

```
:%s/ *; *$/ ;/
```

but that defeats the point of clang-format.  Is there a way to configure such an obscure style preference?

Answer (score 0):

I was using clang-format in vim with the following in my .vimrc:

```
map <C-K> :pyf /usr/share/clang/clang-format.py<cr>
```

I've switched this to:

```
map <C-K> :!mycformat<cr>
```

where that script is just:

```
clang-format | sed 's/ *; *$/ ;/'
```

(this will also work on the command line as a straight up replacement for clang-format).